# How to assign string into MessageBox C++?

Tags: c++, string, netbeans, messagebox

hello this is my simple code. I want to use String in to that MessageBox. I used google. But i have no good solution. I am using netbeans and Mingw.

```
#include <windows.h>
int main()
    {
MessageBox(NULL, "Hello world","Warning!", 
MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
}
```

Now you can see "Hello world" in that messagebox. I want to assign it as a string. Something like this.

```
String mymessage = "Hello world";
```

and call it like this:

```
MessageBox(NULL, mymessage  ,"Warning!", 
    MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
```

I am new to C++. If you having C++ tutorial please list it. Please do not add Visual C++. The google always giving Visual C++ solutions. But that solutions didn't fix my problems. Hope you can understand.

Thank you for your time.

In that case my main thing is assign String and call it for MessageBox.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
MessageBox(NULL, mymessage.c_str()  ,"Warning!", 
    MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
```

Explanation:
the second argument of `MessageBox` should be `const char*`(If macro `UNICODE` is undefined), while `std::string` cannot be implicitly converted to `const char*`. So you should use `const char* c_str() const` method.

Comment: This code will not work!
It'll throwed the following error:
`error C2664: cannot convert argument 2 from 'const char *' to 'LPCWSTR'`

Comment: hello thank you for your idea. How i add this cnst char to my code? can you show me?

Comment: @MirjalalTalishinski You could follow  Algirdas Preidžius's suggestion: this error means the macro `UNICODE` is defined and `MessageBox` is actually `MessageBoxW`. For a quick solution just replace `MessageBox` with `MessageBoxA`.

Comment: @Iz96 as you know, the `MessageBox` was defined in `WinUser.h` file. If you search for *MessageBox* in this file, you can see that, 
`#ifdef UNICODE
#define MessageBox  MessageBoxW
#else
#define MessageBox  MessageBoxA
#endif // !UNICODE`.

 In this part of code the `#else` section is *disabled*. That means, `UNICODE` has already defined.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

MessageBox gets a pointer to a null-terminated string as input, so you need to get the pointer to the string from the string itself, using the c_str() operator:

```
MessageBox(NULL, mymessage.c_str(), ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You couldn't use `std::string` as caption and/or message in `MessageBox`. Because, `MessageBox` accepts the `LPCWSTR` type as its 2nd and 3rd parameters. So, if you want to use *string* in your MessageBox, you must use `std::wstring`.
Example code:

```cpp
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::wstring value = L"Your message goes here";
    MessageBox(NULL, value.c_str(), L"Warning", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not necessarily. All procedures/functions in `windows.h` have both ANSI version, and unicode version. In the case of `MessageBox`, they would be: `MessageBoxA`/`MessageBoxW`. They are then `#define`d to the actual name of `MessageBox` according to `#ifdef UNICODE`. And, looking at his code, you can see that `UNICODE` is not defined.

Comment: @Oldmax what's the error? 
@AlgirdasPreidžius defining `UNICODE` in this program code's not necessary.

Comment: Thank you for your help. i got it and working well. Thank you for your time. keep your job for us.... have a nice day!!

Comment: @Oldmax you are welcome! Oh, it's nice to hear you solved the problem. How did you do this? Can you share the solution with us? 
Have a great day!

Comment: @MirjalalTalishinski I am afraid that it is necessary. Even if it isn't done by you explicitly, it is done by your solution configuration / compiler flags (/D UNICODE). Since otherwise - your `MessageBox` would be defined as `MessageBoxA`, and, hence, would expect ANSI strings.

Comment: Thank you bro, Yes please look @Mirjalal Talishinski. I posted it. As well as i have small problem. Please tell me how to add two String into This type MessageBox.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>

#include <iostream>

#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

main()

{


  string mHeader ="Hello! \n \n";
string mReport ="This is test one! \n \n";

MessageBox(NULL,  mReport.c_str(), "Waring", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);

return 0;

}
```

Hello this is the finally working code. Thank you for your support. without your help i can not able to write and learn this. So Now you can see here having two String : mHeader and mReport. I want to add this two String to my MessageBox. But how i do that? As well as tell me if anything wrong in my code.

Thank you again.